# Why does OS X define 'nil'

Tags: c++, macos

At least the libsigc++2 project is hit by OS X headers defining `nil` on the preprocessor level, outside of namespaces etc. At least 10.5.5 and XCode 3.1 have this. Note that it is in effect not only in Objective-C sources but C++ as well.

Short question: why?

http://ardour.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.5/functor__trait_8h-source.html

p.s. I remember `nil` from Objective-C, too. But I don't see a justification of such a blunt (imho) define for other languages, affecting code that has nothing to do with Objective-C at all (s.a. pure C++ projects).

Comment: Actually, I disagree with you. It is their OS and their modified version of the GCC compiler, if they want to define a non-standard pre-processor symbol that is their prerogative. Microsoft does it all the time. If you don't like their compiler & headers, get different ones.

Comment: Are you sure a PURE C++ project, with just the <std> headers (no system .h headers) gets nil defined?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 10.5.6 and XCode 3.1.2.  I just tried using `nil` on my pure cpp project, and it wasn't defined:

```
main.cpp:41: error: 'nil' was not declared in this scope
```

My guess is that your project is somehow including Cocoa or another Objective-C library.  Perhaps your code is being compiled as Objective-C++?  It can compile any combination of C++ and Objective-C, so existing C++ code may compile.  This is the default for files with the `.mm` extension.

Did you create the XCode project for this library?  If so, perhaps it is using XCode's prefix header that comes with the Framework template, which includes Cocoa/Cocoa.h.  Check the "Prefix Header" option in the project and target info.

I also grepped through /usr/include, and didn't find any instances of `#define nil`.

[Edit: The `.h` file you linked to may `#undef nil` because it can also be used from Objective-C++.]